# Video slideshow, blinking lines

Tags: ffmpeg, mlt

I'm creating video slideshow

```
melt -profile atsc_720p_25 67.jpg length=100 -filter crop center=1 -filter  affine transition.geometry="0=0,0:100%x100%;100=-100,-100:115%x115%" -consumer avformat:out.mp4 vcodec=libx264 vb=3000k
```

And i have blinking lines effect which i don't get when make same slideshow via adobe after effects:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B41pdpunN9o
How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You may be experiencing some interaction between the crop and affine filters. The crop should not be necessary. You can just start the affine with more zoom to achieve the same effect:

```
melt -profile atsc_720p_25 67.jpg length=100 \
   -filter affine transition.geometry="0=0,0:110%x110%;100=-100,-100:125%x125%" \
   -consumer avformat:out.mp4 vcodec=libx264 vb=3000k
```

Set whatever initial zoom is necessary to fill the frame.